# Qt QMessageBox get rid of label left margin

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

I want to display some information message, for that I decided to use `QMessageBox` with no icon, problem is there is a huge gap between left part of widget and text, tried to remove it by setting margins and spacings to 0, but everything was removed except that left part.

Here is a simple example of what I have.

```
QMessageBox messageBox(QMessageBox::NoIcon, "My Title", "This is my text that I want to display.\nBut there is annoying left margin that I can't remove whatever I try.\n", QMessageBox::StandardButton::Ok);
messageBox.exec();
```

[image]

Any ideas how to do that, or I should create my own simple widget?

Comment: There don't seem to be flags for that. We perhaps are expected to design our own dialogs when we want these to be pixel perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I read in the source code of QMessageBox, and see these lines:

```
void QMessageBoxPrivate::setupLayout()
{
    Q_Q(QMessageBox);
    delete q->layout();
    QGridLayout *grid = new QGridLayout;
    bool hasIcon = !iconLabel->pixmap(Qt::ReturnByValue).isNull();

    if (hasIcon)
        grid->addWidget(iconLabel, 0, 0, 2, 1, Qt::AlignTop);
    iconLabel->setVisible(hasIcon);
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
    QSpacerItem *indentSpacer = new QSpacerItem(14, 1, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
#else
    QSpacerItem *indentSpacer = new QSpacerItem(hasIcon ? 7 : 15, 1, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
#endif
    grid->addItem(indentSpacer, 0, hasIcon ? 1 : 0, 2, 1);
    grid->addWidget(label, 0, hasIcon ? 2 : 1, 1, 1);
 ...
```

So the way to remove left space is remove indentSpacer in grid layout:

```
  QMessageBox msgBox(QMessageBox::NoIcon, "My Title", "This is my text that I want to display.\nBut there is annoying left margin that I can't remove whatever I try.\n", QMessageBox::StandardButton::Ok);
  QLabel *msg_label;
  msg_label = msgBox.findChild<QLabel*>("qt_msgbox_label");
  msg_label->setStyleSheet("* { color: blue; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 3; }");

  QGridLayout *lay = msgBox.findChild<QGridLayout *>();
  lay->removeItem(lay->itemAt(0));
  msgBox.exec();
```

Successful image:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also noticed this approach with taking child giving exact name from source code, but was looking for something more legit :D

Comment: Yes, move on! : D